# Is a random walk cointegrated with its own lag?

Tags: time-series, cointegration, definition, random-walk

Can a random walk, or more broadly a unit-root process, be considered cointegrated with its own lag? E.g. if $y_t=y_{t-1}+u_t$ with $u_t\sim$ i.i.d., then $y_t$ is I(1), $x_t:=y_{t-1}$ is I(1) and there exists a $\beta$ (namely, $\beta=-1$) such that $y_t+\beta x_t$ is I(0). Formally, the requirements of cointegration appear to be satisfied: each process is I(1) but there exists a linear combination that is I(0).

(This is a duplicate of [this question](https://economics.stackexchange.com/questions/47208) on Economics SE. I am cross-posting this here as I am not convinced by the answers at Economics SE and would like to draw on the extensive time series expertise available on Cross Validated.)

Comment: I don't see any reason why you couldn't call it that.

Comment: Hi Rochard: the notion of cointegration has it's origins in the concept of spurious regression: if one has 2 random walks that are regressed on each other, then it's possible to get spurious results. Considering the changes of each of the series was a solution but it was frowned up because the levels information was lost. So, engle and granger figured out  how to retain long term level info and and changes. So, I see what you mean about cointegration holding with $y_{t-1} = x_{t}$ but it kind of muddles what e and g were getting at which was how to deal with relations between two series.

Comment: @mlofton The definition of cointegration does not preclude this situation, so it's largely irrelevant what they were "getting at". This is no different than the fact that the covariance of a random variable with itself is the same as the variance. Sure, *usually* you take two "different" random variables, but nothing in the definition says they *must* be.

Comment: @ChrisHaug, AndrewM's answer on Economics SE suggests an integrated variable and its lag cannot be considered cointegrated as the rank of the $\Pi$ matrix of the VECM representation of their system is zero. Would you have any comment on that?

Comment: Hi Richard: Andrew M's answer shows that the rank of the $\pi$ matrix is zero which corresponds to case 2 in the paper ( see bottom of 170)  which, according to Johansen and Juselius is the standard vector differenced time series model. Clearly, even though they don't say it explicitly, they imply that case 2 is not a case of cointegration. As you say, Andrew M's answer is quite convincing.

Comment: I don't believe that the setup of that answer is sufficiently clear or rigorous to evaluate. What are the implied conditions on $v_t$? There exists a stationary $v_t$ where such a representation with $\Pi$ having rank 1 exists: take $v_t = [u_t, 0]'$, $\alpha = [0, 1]'$, $\beta = [1, -1]'$, and $\Pi = \alpha \beta'$.

Comment: @ChrisHaug, comments like this justify my idea to ask the question here in addition to having it on Economics SE :)

Comment: @ChrisHaug is imposing additonal restrictions on the residuals. That is not the same unrestricted regression as in my answer.

Comment: Also the just because you are showing that the system can be of reduced rank does not imply that you are proving that the system is cointegrated. Reduced rank is a necessary but not a sufficient condition for cointegration since a stationary VAR can also have a reduced rank.

Comment: @AndrewM, thank you, this seems to be moving the discussion in a promissing direction!

Comment: @AndrewM Could you clarify what you mean by "imposing restrictions"? There's no optimization or fitting of any kind here so it's unclear what you would be "restricting". What I've exhibited is simply the model as defined above, cast into the general form from the paper. The fact that this involves one of the error terms being zero is not a *restriction*, it's a *special case*. On the other hand, what you've exhibited is *not* of the general form from the paper so what, precisely, is the argument here?

Comment: @ChrisHaug the model you specified based on your parameterization is not a bivariate system. It is a single equation and an identity (by imposing a zero restriction on the on the second equation's residual). Thus, the reduced rank discussion is mute because you are effectively only working with one equation.

Comment: @AndrewM I have "imposed" no restrictions whatsoever. In fact, you have, by imposing dynamic structure on $v_t$ (i.e. that the first component of $v_{t-1}$ is exactly equal to the second component of $v_t$).

Comment: @ChrisHaug well we you can argue terminology all you want. The fact still stands that your parameterization does not imply a two equation system and so the reduced rank discussion is meaningless.